# Android: How to update a TextView in swipe view sibling fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe

I implemented swipe views in my app following this guide: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging

In my Fragment, I have a TextView, whos content might get updated due to user action. This update is not reflected, when I swipe to another sibling (left or right).

Furthermore, once I have swiped to another Fragment and perform an action to update the TextViews content, the text does not update. However, when I swipe back to the Fragment I came from, the TextView in the first fragment reflects the update I made in the second fragment.

I call upon the TextView by its ID. Looks like, this doesn't get me the TextView in the actual fragment, but always and only the one in the first fragment.

I would like to accomplish two things:

1. When I swipe to another fragment, I would like the TextView to always show the actual value.
2. When I perform an action in a Fragment other then the first, I would like the TextView of the current Fragment to get updated.

Comment: Have you wired up your fragment messaging? http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Wow.. that looks convoluted and quite unintuitive. Is that the recommended way just to get the right TextView?

Comment: Welcome to the Android party bro! A good source reference is key http://androidxref.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since said TextView should be shown in every fragment, it shouldn't be part of the fragment in the first place, but should belong to the parent activity. This way, it can be modified easily from any fragment and always accesses the right one, since there is only one.